# How to get data from a dynamically created Collection in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

we have a collection say TestColl

having document like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57558a793f50f61400af205c"),
    "title" : "Tile 1",
    "addSites" : true,
    "version" : 11,
    "isMajorVersion" : true
},
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("654558a793f50f61400af205c"),
    "title" : "Title 2,
    "addSites" : false,
    "version" : 11,
    "isMajorVersion" : true
}
```

for every documemt of TestColl there is a separete collection in DB

so we have another two collections which is created based upon the object Id of TestColl which is 
`57558a793f50f61400af205c` and `654558a793f50f61400af205c`

this makes total three collections.

looking for a way to access a collection '57558a793f50f61400af205c' if my query returns document having _id=654558a793f50f61400af205c in a single query.

**Constraint** : we need only query without creating any stored procedure or function just pure mongodb query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use forEach loop and access data from collection like this:

```
db.kt.find().forEach(function(doc){
    var colName = doc._id.str;
    var data = db.getCollection(colName).find().toArray();
    printjson(data);
    print(","); // to have array of arrays [[],[],[]]
    })
```

Comment: Thank you Man . It is working now .you saved my Tens of Hours.

Comment: Add line printjson(doc)